# When I try to run any npm command am getting spawn bash ENOENT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

[Here is the error that am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHlYa.png)

When I try to run any npm command am getting error as spawn bash ENOENT so am not able to proceed Please can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are in the right directory and the correct file. I believe this may be the reason. I did a quick search and it may be that in the current file or directory the file does not exist. Hope that helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missing something. Try this:

- delete node-modules
- run command `npm cache clean --force`
- run command `npm install`

This will be reinstall all dependencies

Comment: Quick check you picture. I realize that this error cause by sass module. So Did you try other version of this modeule?